# The Probability Generating Function of the Total Population

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, markov-chains, markov-process

**Branching Process**

if initial population $0$ is equal to $1$, i.e. $X_0 \equiv 1$

and $S_k$ is the total population size up to
generation $k$ meaning $S_k = 1 +X_1 +...+X_k$.

If $G(z)$ is the Probability Generating Function of the number of offspring produced by a single member.

and $H_k(z) $ is the The Probability Generating Function  of $S_k$.

what is the relationship between $H_k(z)$ and $H_{k-1}(z)$

My calculation gave me the following relationship, but I am not sure:

$$H_k(z) = G(H_{k-1}(z))$$

Comment: Your calculation is correct.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, why do I need the fact that population zero equals $1$ and where do I use that fact. Also is this a sound proof $H_k(z) = E[Z^{S_k}]= E[E[Z^{S_k}|S_{k-1}]] = E[z^{H_{k-1}(s)}] = G[H_{k-1}(s)]$

Comment: If the population at time $0$ is $n$ then $G$ gets replaced by $G^{n}$. Your argument for showing that $H_k=G\circ H_{k-1}$ is not correct. How do you know that $Ez^{S_k}|S_{k-1} =z^{H_{k-1}(s)}$?. Besides the last step is also wrong because $z^{H_{k-1}}$ is just a number not a random variable. How do you write this as $G[H_{k-1} (s)]$?

Comment: $G[H_{k-1}(s)] = E[(H_{k-1}(s))^X]$ Since $G$ is pgf of offspring produced by one member, then $X$ ought to equal $1$ so $G[H_{k-1}(s)] = E[(H_{k-1}(s))]$

Comment: You are getting  a bit confused with definition of generating function. $G(t)=Et^{S_1}$. $H_{k-1}(s)$ is just a number, not a random variable. Why are you taking its expectation?.

Comment: Sorry I corrected my answer while you were posting your message. I get confused when 2 pgf's are involved. that's true.

Comment: Does it equal $G[H_{k−1}(s)]= E[(H_{k−1}(s))^{X_0}]$

Comment: It is $E[(H_{k-1}(s)^{X_1}]$ if you assume that $X_0=1$.

Comment: That is true. $G(s)=G_{X_1}(s)$ because $G_{X_0}(s) =s$ I think I am starting to understand.

Comment: If I condition on $X_1 = m$, what would $E[Z^{S_k}| X_1 = m]  = E[Z^{1+m+X_2+...}| X_1 = m] $ look like?